# IOS How to detect an Alert is added as subview

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

How to identify a alert is currently displaying in application.

iterating thru uiapplication's windows subview doesnt gives the object of alert which is added.

Edit:
Also is it possible to detect inbuilt alert like location opt alert, APNS enable alert ?

Comment: Why not just adding your AlretView as an ivar and check `_alert.visible`

Comment: Sorry If you post some code. that will be very helpful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your alert is displayed during the period you show it and hide it. If you need to do something on these events, observe them in your delegate.

It's also possible to check `[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow`. When the alert is shown, the key window is a system window (the class name starts with an `_`).

It's not possible to detect any system alerts (APNS alert etc.) for security reasons.